# Understanding of the expand command

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I can't fully understand how the `-t` parameter of the `expand` command work. Below is an excerpt from its manpage.

```
NAME
       expand - convert tabs to spaces
...

-t, --tabs=N
       have tabs N characters apart, not 8
```

What exactly does *have tabs N characters apart* mean? I did some testing.

```
root@u2004:~# printf "a\tb\n"
a   b
root@u2004:~# printf "a\tb\n" | od -a
0000000   a  ht   b  nl
0000004
root@u2004:~# printf "a\tb\n" | expand | od -a
0000000   a  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   b  nl
0000012
root@u2004:~# printf "a\tb\n" | expand -t 4 | od -a
0000000   a  sp  sp  sp   b  nl
0000006
root@u2004:~# printf "a\tb\n" | expand -t 5 | od -a
0000000   a  sp  sp  sp  sp   b  nl
0000007
root@u2004:~#
```

As you can see, when I pass `-t 4`, the tab was replaced to 3 spaces. So, in reality, "have tabs 4 characters apart" just means tabs were replace with 3 spaces? I can't understand. Btw, I'm not a native English speaker and it's possible that this is an English related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to tab *stops*, the positions where the tab jumps to. With `-t 4`, there's a tab stop every four characters.

A tab doesn't insert a fixed number of spaces, but jumps to the next such position, so the amount of spaces added
depends on how long the text before the tab was. E.g.:

```
$ printf "1\tx\n" | expand -t 4 | od -a
0000000    1  sp  sp  sp   x  nl                                        
0000006
$ printf "123\tx\n" | expand -t 4 | od -a
0000000    1   2   3  sp   x  nl                                        
0000006
```

The point of course is to get the columns to line up:

```
$ printf "123\tx\n1\tx\n" |expand -t4
123 x
1   x
```

So, to try to represent it visually, the tab-stop placement there is like this, with `^` showing the stops:

```
123412341234...
^   ^   ^
```

(Of course you can't tab to the very start, so the first one isn't really there.)

That gets messed up if one field is longer than the tab-stop distance, though, but `expand` takes a list of column positions as an alternative, e.g. this has a four-wide column and an eight-wide column:

```
$ printf "%b\n" 'A\t1234567\thello' 'B\t987\tworld' |expand  -t4,12
A   1234567 hello
B   987     world
```

There, the stops are like so:

```
          11111111112
012345678901234567890...
A   1234567 hello
B   987     world
    ^       ^
```

I started the numbering from zero there, so that the positions match the numbers given on the command line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's much clearer now. For POSIX compliant tools, normally, how many characters are used for a tabstop?

Comment: @FajelaTajkiya, hmm, I'm not sure how many places it would come up in. `expand` (and `unexpand`) default to 8, but other than that, I think it mostly comes up when printing to the terminal. And that's up to the terminal settings. (I would _expect_ full-screen editors to deal with tabs themselves, again, by configuration). But for the usual text-processing tools (awk, cut, sed, shell language functions, whatever), the tab is just a single character, mostly like space.

Comment: Thanks again for the insights!